# asp.net core 2 angular template - where to add third party assets

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

it looks like everything in the clientapp folder is compiled into javascript and bundled into main-client.js using webpack, probably. i don't know much about it.

what i'm wondering is, if i have some javascript and css that isn't strictly part of the angular app, where in the project do i add these dependencies. do i add it in the dist folder? it looks like that folder is dynamically created by webpack so i didn't want to do that.

for example, the default angular app it installs clearly uses bootstrap for css grid system classes, so bootstrap must be installed somewhere. is it in the webpack config? how would i go about adding any other third party assets or my own?

thanks for any clarity about using this template

Comment: are you using VS Code or VS Studio?

Comment: visual studio 2017

Comment: not offering as this as an answer because the How-Tos and docs are so all over the place, I'm not sure if its right, but this is how I do it:  In your solution, expand webpack.config.js, and you should see a webpack.config.vendor.js.  Inside that, you should see a section titled "nonTreeShakableModules".  That's where I insert all my 3rd party css and js.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/) by Steve Sanderson, who is apparently the author of  this template you are referring to, the intended order of operations to add third party node modules is:

1. Add the module to your package.json file, save and then restore npm packages,
2. Add the item to the `vendor` array in `webpack.config.vendor.js` (which is the same as adding the item to the `nonTreeShakableModules` in the same file as Mike_G mentioned),
3. Run `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` to repack your new assets. Make sure to install webpack with npm before this step.

It may be worth mentioning that Steve says that in step number 2, if what is being added is a css asset, the full path within node_modules and extension are needed, i.e. `font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css`, but if you are only including a Javascript library, then just the name of library will suffice, i.e. `moment` for `Moment.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Well since **webpack** is being used, there is no way of adding any JS or CSS code inside that `budnle.js` file.
You would have to create you code before the packaging is being run.

The other way is to create your files and import them manually in t he `index.html` file.

This is ad hock way of doing stuff, but only in case that you need to add some CSS code to your project and not having knowledge of angular/webpack stuff.
As for JS code, its nearly impossible to add anything like that, since html code is also compiled and sent into `bundle.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two ways:
1) use angular/cli. In .angular-cli.json you can find:

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css"
],
"scripts": [],
```

here you can add any custom css or js file.
2) work with static files: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files
in this second way you can set a specific folder, add any custom file css or js and link to it from _layout.cshtml file.
hope this help u